# Hosting MySQL database on ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and I want to know how can I upload a MySQL database to an EC2 instance.

I watched some tutorials and created new instances and set group rules like this:

```
SSH - TCP - PORT 20

MySql/Aurora - TCP - PORT 3306
```

but It doesn't work and I can't even get the command line of the instance.

Comment: What "doesn't work" **specifically**?

Comment: i cant even connect to the EC2 command line

Comment: Why not use the RDS Service and setup a MySQL instance.

Comment: You need to focus on one thing at a time. The MySQL aspect of your question is totally irrelevant since you haven't even connected to the server yet to install MySQL. You need to focus on being able to SSH into the instance. You should edit your question to include the exact command you are using to connect to the instance, along with the error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

SSH port is 22. Why are you using 20?
allow HTTPS from anywhere for now. Install all required applications & then see if you can use mysql.

Once you install mysql, you can use the dump option to make it running in your EC2